# Connection could not be established with host on custom server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i am using laravel 5.1 &
i am trying to send email after login but it show me error

> Connection Could not be established with host mail.jobnow.com.sg

also try another host like gmail and other still same problem

How can i fix this

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? Some shared hosting are blocking external email port.

Comment: no i am using aws server with paid cpanel

Comment: Try check it manually in your server via `telnet`: `telnet mail.jobnow.com.sg PORTNUMBER`. You should get result `220 mail.jobnow.com.sg`. If not, check your server configuration, the port may blocked.

Comment: i have another domain hosted in same cpanel called digibull360.com and its working fine every email is coming and shooting 
yes i tried mail.digibull360.com still same problem i think something problem with swiftmailer